# Custom operations when creating an SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Say I have a set of users, a set of games, and I track whether a user has finished a game in a separate table (name: 'game_progress'). I want it to be that whenever a user is created, the 'game_progress' table is auto-populated with her ID and a 'No' against all the available games. (I know that I can wait until she starts a game to create the record, but, I need this for an altogether different purpose.) How would I go about doing this?

I tried using the after_insert() event. But, then I can't retrieve the ID of the User to insert into 'game_progress'. I don't want to use after_flush (even if I can figure out how to do it) because it may be a bit of an overkill, as the user creation operation doesn't happen that often.

```
class Game(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'games'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(30))

class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(30))

class GameProgress(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'game_progress'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    game_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('games.id'), primary_key=True)
    game_finished = db.Column(db.Boolean)

@event.listens_for(User, "after_insert")
def after_insert(mapper, connection, target):
    progress_table = GameProgress.__table__
    user_id = target.id
    connection.execute(
        progress_table.insert().\
            values(user_id=user_id, game_id=1, game_finished=0)
    )

db.create_all()
game = Game(name='Solitaire')
db.session.add(game)
db.session.commit()
user = User(name='Alice')
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Normally you'd use DB triggers for such, or just include the creation of the required additional data in your logic of creating a new user, which means write a function that handles creating users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything fancy with triggers or event listeners at all, you can just set up the relations and then make related objects in the constructor for User. As long as you have defined relationships (which you're not doing at present, you'd only added the foreign keys), then you don't need User to have an id to set up the associated objects. Your constructor can just do something like this:

`class User(db.Model):
        def __init__(self, all_games, **kwargs):
            for k,v in kwargs.items():
                setattr(self, k, v) 
            for game in all_games:
                self.game_progresses.append( GameProgress(game=game, \
                                     user=self, game_finished=False) )`

When you commit the user, you'll also commit a list of GameProgress objects, one for each game. But the above depends on you setting up relationships on all your objects. You need to add the below to GameProgress class

`game = relationship("Game", backref="game_progresses")
user = relationship("User", backref="game_progresses")`

And pass in a list of games to user when you make your user:

`all_games = dbs.query(Game).all()
new_user = User(all_games=all_games, name="Iain")`

Once that's done you can just add GameProgress objects to the instrumented list user.game_progresses and you don't need to have committed anything before the first commit. SQLA will chase through all the relationships. Basically any time you need to muck with an id directly, ask yourself if you're using the ORM right, you rarely need to. The ORM tutorial on the SQLA docs goes through this very well. There are lots of options you can pass to relationships and backrefs to get the cascading doing what you want.

Comment: Perfect. "any time you need to muck with an id directly, ask yourself if you're using the ORM right" Will bear that in mind. Thanks!